# Where can I find Tubbies and Chubbies

Tags: borderlands-2

Where is the best place to spawn and find Chubbies and Tubbies? I know them to drop legendaries and pearlescents.

Comment: Wildlife Preservation . . .
get Doctor Order sidequest , but  DO NOT pick any quest item for it.
one of quest item is inside a box. . . 
there was 4 box near it, and all of them is ALWAYS spawn Loot Midget. . .

Comment: One place that spawn Chubbys is beneath Sanctuary, the Caustic Caverns. Chubbys come from the trash trucks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are playing on Ultimate Vault Hunter More, then you can easily find Tubby spider ants behind Ellie's garage in the dust. If you don't get any to spawn the first time, then simply exit, rinse and repeat.